# I have a specific date/time object I need to output as a strings

Tags: php, datetime

I have this specific object (var_dumped here), it contains date and time info.

```
object(stdClass)#5467 (3) { ["__CLASS__"]=> string(8) "DateTime" ["date"]=> string(25) "2016-12-09T05:21:00+00:00" ["timezone"]=> string(3) "UTC" }
```

I need to output the date as a string`(m jS Y)` and the time as a string`(g:ia)` but for the life of me I am having no luck making it do so for some reason. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you have trouble accessing the property or doing the conversion

Comment: Doing the conversion... so the object is represented by a variable. `$myDateTimeObject` for example. I have tried to just run it through `$turnToDateTimeDamnIt = strtotime($myDateTimeObject)` but it is expecting a string not a object. Feels like this should be obvious to do but I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, so this is a php [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object. To format it, you'd use something like:

```
$myDateTimeObject->format('m jS Y');
// or if you want brackets: $myDateTimeObject->format('\(m jS Y\)');
```

and

```
$myDateTimeObject->format('g:ia');
// or if you want brackets: $myDateTimeObject->format('\(g:ia\)');
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah, that's ridiculously simple. I thought I had to convert it to a string first and do like `date('m jS Y', $myNowStringDateTime);` Good grief. Thanks so much, that is fantastic.